# while npm build server that time geting error not building

Tags: server, npm-build

i **getting npm build error at server directory** while building `npm build`
log if pasted below and also package.json file also added any suggetions what problem..?

```
Mar 18 03:55:19 PM  ==> Cloning from https://github.com/kirankuyate2157/refine_dashboard...
Mar 18 03:55:20 PM  ==> Checking out commit 1222bafece9a938731793c8fd4b5395a3380d259 in branch main
Mar 18 03:55:25 PM  ==> Running build command 'npm'...
Mar 18 03:55:25 PM  
Mar 18 03:55:25 PM  Usage: npm <command>
Mar 18 03:55:25 PM  
Mar 18 03:55:25 PM  where <command> is one of:
Mar 18 03:55:25 PM      access, adduser, audit, bin, bugs, c, cache, ci, cit,
Mar 18 03:55:25 PM      clean-install, clean-install-test, completion, config,
Mar 18 03:55:25 PM      create, ddp, dedupe, deprecate, dist-tag, docs, doctor,
Mar 18 03:55:25 PM      edit, explore, fund, get, help, help-search, hook, i, init,
Mar 18 03:55:25 PM      install, install-ci-test, install-test, it, link, list, ln,
Mar 18 03:55:25 PM      login, logout, ls, org, outdated, owner, pack, ping, prefix,
Mar 18 03:55:25 PM      profile, prune, publish, rb, rebuild, repo, restart, root,
Mar 18 03:55:25 PM      run, run-script, s, se, search, set, shrinkwrap, star,
Mar 18 03:55:25 PM      stars, start, stop, t, team, test, token, tst, un,
Mar 18 03:55:25 PM      uninstall, unpublish, unstar, up, update, v, version, view,
Mar 18 03:55:25 PM      whoami
Mar 18 03:55:25 PM  
Mar 18 03:55:25 PM  npm <command> -h  quick help on <command>
Mar 18 03:55:25 PM  npm -l            display full usage info
Mar 18 03:55:25 PM  npm help <term>   search for help on <term>
Mar 18 03:55:25 PM  npm help npm      involved overview
Mar 18 03:55:25 PM  
Mar 18 03:55:25 PM  Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
Mar 18 03:55:25 PM      /opt/render/.npmrc
Mar 18 03:55:25 PM  or on the command line via: npm <command> --key value
Mar 18 03:55:25 PM  Config info can be viewed via: npm help config
Mar 18 03:55:25 PM  
Mar 18 03:55:25 PM  npm@6.14.13 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
Mar 18 03:55:25 PM  ==> Build failed 
Mar 18 03:55:25 PM  ==> Generating container image from build. This may take a few minutes...
```

my server  package.json  file

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cloudinary": "^1.35.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mongoose": "^7.0.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.21"
  }
}
```

> while building it getting error
> what should i do..help
> @npmbuild
> **your text**

what wrong is there in mys side and how to resolve it

Comment: resolved
i missed build script after adding it working

Answer (score 0):

after **adding the build script** it working

script was

```
"scripts": {
"start": "nodemon index",
"build": "npm install && npm run build-server",
"build-server": "echo 'Building server...' && npm run compile-server",
"compile-server": "echo 'Compiling server...'"
},
```

add build cmd `npm run build` while deploying after that `npm start`
it is working and live now server